# Request help for reading text data files with headers and 2 sections

Tags: data

I just started with *Mathematica*.

I need it for many purposes, but the important one is to read a text data file and extract column values as variables.

I have successfully tested the tab delimited data format. Now I have a problem with a file with this format:

> 15 lines of comments with spaces and blank lines
>   7 col and 100 lines: Col haves headers.
>   The above is repeated after 3 blanks lines.

Any comments and suggestions are welcome

Comment: You've seen `Import[]`?

Comment: Hi belisarius
Thank you.
Yes I tested Import function but no succes.
Here you can find my data:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/82n3dubfwbstns5/exampleDataFile.txt
Best regards

Comment: Hi Andre  Thank you.

Comment: Please find the link to my data: https://www.dropbox.com/s/82n3dubfwbstns5/exampleDataFile.txt

Comment: Andre, Please can you comment or give some details about your code?

Comment: I cannot seem to download the file; I get only: **Loading...** Can anyone else?

Comment: @andre If you please, what browser are you using?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/82n3dubfwbstns5/exampleDataFile.txt   This link will work is you copy paste

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Firefox

Answer (score 3):

**Preamble : Input file**

[image]

**solution**
Here is how I would do It :

```
Import[filename, "Text"] // (* import the whole file as a unique string *)
      StringSplit[#, "\n\n\n"] & // (* split every time there are 3 carriage return -> separate blocks *)
     (StringSplit[#, "\n"] & /@ # &) // (* split in the inner structures at every car ret -> separate lines in each block*)
    (Drop[#, 15] & /@ # &) // (* get rid of the 15 first lines in inner structures *)
   (Drop[#, 1] & /@ # &) // (* get rid of the next line -> remove headlines *)
  Map[StringSplit[#, "\t"] &, #, {2}] & // (* split at every tab in inner structures of level 2 -> separate numbers in each line *)
 Map[StringReplace[#, " " -> ""] &, #, {2}] & (* suppress parasitical white characters at level 2 *)
```

At this point each number is a String. You can use `ImportString["8.17464362e-04", "Table"]` to get the number or see [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1737/how-do-you-convert-a-string-containing-a-number-in-c-scientific-notation-to-a-ma).

To understand my code, try :
- first `Import[filename, "Text"]`
- then `Import[filename, "Text"] //StringSplit[#, "\n\n\n"] &`
- then `Import[filename, "Text"] //StringSplit[#, "\n\n\n"] & //(StringSplit[#, "\n"]`
- etc ...

**Edit**

The same code, in a more classical coding style :

```
fullText = Import[filename, "Text"];
splitLevel1 = StringSplit[fullText, "\n\n\n"];
splitLevel2 = Map[StringSplit[#, "\n"] &, splitLevel1];
splitLevel2WithoutHeadLines = Map[Drop[#, 16] &, splitLevel2];
splitLevel3 = Map[StringSplit[#, "\t"] &, splitLevel2WithoutHeadLines, {2}];
splitLevel3WithoutWhiteCharacters = Map[StringReplace[#, " " -> ""] &, splitLevel3, {2}]
```

**Verification**

[image]

Comment: Hi Andre and Wizard, Thank you very much for your very fast and efficient helps! I have to working solutions which can be very helpfull!

Comment: Hi Andre Thank you again. It work well and the code is clear! How to plot column 2 vs column 1

Answer (score 1):

This is not likely to be particularly fast, but it is concise:

```
Cases[
 Import["exampleDataFile.txt", "Table"],
 {__?NumberQ}
]
```

Should there be false matches you can use the known number of columns:

```
Cases[
 Import["exampleDataFile.txt", "Table"],
 {Repeated[_?NumberQ, {7}]}
]
```

If you need to separate each block of numeric data you might use `SplitBy` as follows:

```
dat = Import["exampleDataFile.txt", "Table"];

SplitBy[dat, MatchQ[#, {Repeated[_, {7}]?NumberQ}] &][[2 ;; -1 ;; 2]]
```

If any of these methods do not work on your full set please consider uploading a second example data file.

---

If the rest of the file is as regular as this appears you could try using `Read` and related functions for greater performance, as shown [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/20847/121).  For example:

```
skip[__String] = Sequence[];

line = Table[Number, {7}];
drop = skip @@ Table[Record, {12}];
spec = Join[{drop}, Table[line, {21}]];

ReadList["exampleDataFile.txt", spec]
```

> ```
> {{{100., 41.2318, 1.31655*10^-9, 1.96161, -38600., 38600., -89.9971}, {158.489, 41.2318, 
>    3.22439*10^-9, 1.91259, -24355., 24355., -89.9955}, {251.189, 41.2318, 8.01648*10^-9, 
>    1.89304, -15367., 15367., -89.9929}, {398.107, 41.2318, 2.00525*10^-8, 
>    1.88515, -9695.9, 9695.9, -89.9889}, {630.957, 41.2316, 5.02786*10^-8, 
>    1.88175, -6117.72, 6117.72, -89.9824}, {1000., 41.2313, 1.26158*10^-7, 
>    1.87975, -3860.05, 3860.05, -89.9721}, {1584.89, 41.2305, 3.16473*10^-7, 
>    1.87732, -2435.57, 2435.57, -89.9558}, {2511.89, 41.2286, 7.92735*10^-7, 
>    1.87228, -1536.81, 1536.81, -89.9302}, {3981.07, 41.2238, 1.97791*10^-6, 
>    1.86016, -969.775, 969.777, -89.8901}, {6309.57, 41.2119, 4.88673*10^-6, 
>    1.83067, -612.059, 612.062, -89.8286}, {10000., 41.1839, 0.0000117939, 
>    1.7613, -386.441, 386.445, -89.7389}, {15848.9, 41.1232, 0.0000270225, 
>    1.61129, -244.183, 244.188, -89.6219}, {25118.9, 41.0111, 0.0000560277, 
>    1.33723, -154.485, 154.491, -89.5041}, {39810.7, 40.8533, 0.000100044, 
>    0.957928, -97.8478, 97.8525, -89.4391}, {63095.7, 40.6927, 0.000153468, 
>    0.589637, -61.9818, 61.9846, -89.455}, {100000., 40.563, 0.000214301, 
>    0.329894, -39.2338, 39.2351, -89.5182}, {158489., 40.4627, 0.000285002, 
>    0.175532, -24.8167, 24.8173, -89.5947}, {251189., 40.3884, 0.000360826, 
>    0.0887994, -15.6873, 15.6876, -89.6757}, {398107., 40.3415, 0.000444295, 
>    0.0436315, -9.90969, 9.90978, -89.7477}, {630957., 40.315, 0.000569237, 
>    0.0222841, -6.25674, 6.25678, -89.7959}, {1.*10^6, 40.2996, 0.000817464, 
>    0.0127498, -3.94925, 3.94927, -89.815}}, {{100., 41.2318, 1.31655*10^-9, 
>    1.96161, -38600., 38600., -89.9971}, {158.489, 41.2318, 3.22439*10^-9, 
>    1.91259, -24355., 24355., -89.9955}, {251.189, 41.2318, 8.01648*10^-9, 
>    1.89304, -15367., 15367., -89.9929}, {398.107, 41.2318, 2.00525*10^-8, 
>    1.88515, -9695.9, 9695.9, -89.9889}, {630.957, 41.2316, 5.02786*10^-8, 
>    1.88175, -6117.72, 6117.72, -89.9824}, {1000., 41.2313, 1.26158*10^-7, 
>    1.87975, -3860.05, 3860.05, -89.9721}, {1584.89, 41.2305, 3.16473*10^-7, 
>    1.87732, -2435.57, 2435.57, -89.9558}, {2511.89, 41.2286, 7.92735*10^-7, 
>    1.87228, -1536.81, 1536.81, -89.9302}, {3981.07, 41.2238, 1.97791*10^-6, 
>    1.86016, -969.775, 969.777, -89.8901}, {6309.57, 41.2119, 4.88673*10^-6, 
>    1.83067, -612.059, 612.062, -89.8286}, {10000., 41.1839, 0.0000117939, 
>    1.7613, -386.441, 386.445, -89.7389}, {15848.9, 41.1232, 0.0000270225, 
>    1.61129, -244.183, 244.188, -89.6219}, {25118.9, 41.0111, 0.0000560277, 
>    1.33723, -154.485, 154.491, -89.5041}, {39810.7, 40.8533, 0.000100044, 
>    0.957928, -97.8478, 97.8525, -89.4391}, {63095.7, 40.6927, 0.000153468, 
>    0.589637, -61.9818, 61.9846, -89.455}, {100000., 40.563, 0.000214301, 
>    0.329894, -39.2338, 39.2351, -89.5182}, {158489., 40.4627, 0.000285002, 
>    0.175532, -24.8167, 24.8173, -89.5947}, {251189., 40.3884, 0.000360826, 
>    0.0887994, -15.6873, 15.6876, -89.6757}, {398107., 40.3415, 0.000444295, 
>    0.0436315, -9.90969, 9.90978, -89.7477}, {630957., 40.315, 0.000569237, 
>    0.0222841, -6.25674, 6.25678, -89.7959}, {1.*10^6, 40.2996, 0.000817464, 
>    0.0127498, -3.94925, 3.94927, -89.815}}}
> ```

The various repetition number in `Table` will need to be adjusted to match your data.  If these many vary the `Import` method would be preferred.

Comment: I get blank list with your code.

Comment: @user6726 does `Import["exampleDataFile.txt", "Table"]` import correctly? (By correctly I just mean all the data there, but not formatted/extracted correctly.)

Comment: Sorry for my previous comment! I set my directory correctly now and get data with your second code! Now I am trying to understand the output!

Comment: It seems that I have the whole data in a big list : Nested list? How to extract colon data?

Comment: @user6726 I don't know what you mean by "colon data." The `Import` method puts all the data in one table of seven columns, whereas the `ReadList` method is producing a list of tables (tensor).  Is one of these correct, or do you need something else?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Assuming these aren't medical data, perhaps it's 'Column Data"?

Comment: @user6726 I added another method to my answer, using `SplitBy` -- there are many ways to approach a problem like this and it's really a matter of what you want and what the full file looks like.

Comment: It is Column. The data is organize in sets of  columns and lines. For each set there are 7 columns and 21 lines (the number of a not fixed, it can be more than 21). In the present example there are 2 sets. So my question is : How can I separate the sets? Idealy I would like to have one table per set (7 columns, Xnumbers of Lines). Thank you